# The directline api uses the id and name to authenticate but the name never persists through when a conversation is subscribed to and activity is sent

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

Here is an example of when I authenticate using directline.

```js
{
  "user": {
    "id": "string",
    "name": "string"
  },
  "trustedOrigins": [
    "string"
  ]
}
1. user.id  string  Optional. Channel-specific ID of the user to encode within the token. For a Direct Line user, this must begin with dl_. You can create a unique user ID for each conversation, and for better security, you should make this ID unguessable.

2. user.name    string  Optional. The display-friendly name of the user to encode within the token.
```

Now, I would expect that the token I receive has the id and the name inside which it does.
Here is an example of the token response:

```js
{
  "bot": "my-bot",
  "site": "ddddddd",
  "conv": "xxxxxxxxx-j",
  "user": "77777777777",
  "username": "{\"first\":\"Christian\",\"last\":\"Matthew\"}",
  "nbf": 1592789668,
  "exp": 1592793268,
  "iss": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
  "aud": "https://directline.botframework.com/"
}
```

Now, when I use this token to start a conversation the token works as epected.

The error comes or unexpected return is when I send an activity to that conversation. The from is the correct id userId but the name isn't there.
Is it there in the bot communication? I would like for the name field to be there. Perhaps it is just not posted in the front-end client message return.

Here is an example of the message that is returned.

```js
message received:
{
  "activities": [
    {
      "type":"message",
      "id":"DtjXwD1VvG7Eu69LR5ZL31-6|0000002",
      "timestamp":"2020-06-22T01:58:16.379228Z",
      "serviceUrl":"https://directline.botframework.com/",
      "channelId":"directline",
      "from": {
        "id":"77777777777"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "id":"DtjXwD1VvG7Eu69LR5ZL31-6"
      },
      "recipient": {
        "id":"xxxxx-xxxxx-bot@2MnpO8SotMQ",
        "name":"xxxxx-xxxxx-bot"
      },
      "text":"xxxxxxx xxxxxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

The id is all that comes through. Is the userName or name available inside of the bot service?  I need to capture that.

**UPDATE:** Add reference to the directline conversation starter token.

`POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations`
`Authorization: Bearer SECRET_OR_TOKEN`

Comment: Can you update your post to include the full direct line API call? And, what are you using as your client? Web Chat or some other service?

Comment: Hi @StevenKanberg this is just a authentication token and then a subsequent start of a conversation. No matter what you use the same conversation starter is used through the sdk, webchat or direct api

Comment: Web Chat allows for overriding the name. I wanted to be sure that wasn't a factor here. In any event, it looks like you asked [this question](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/issues/291) in the BotFramework-DirectLineJS repo. I'll respond there due to the _potential_ for this to be an issue.